# IIS 8.5 - OK button is grey when trying to add port 80 binding w/o hostname

Tags: iis-8.5

I need to reassign the default port 80 binding from one site to another. I remove it from site1 but now cannot add it back on site2, the OK button is gray.

Nothing else is sucking on port 80.

[image: Nothing on port 80]

And it won't let me add port 80 without a hostname.

[image: Grey OK]

I've restarted IIS but it just won't give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a bug in the UI. You need to enter something in the hostname box and then delete it to enable the OK button!

Comment: I'm utterly astonished that this is a real bug in IIS. How does something this fundamental not only get through QA but not get patched after all this time?

Comment: I worked for MS in 1999 when Windows 2000 was beta. Some of the UI, I remember thinking "this is bad, they won't leave it like this, its just a beta". I now have kids and am greying and yet I still encounter those bad UI designs every day. Amazing.